# Conditional Formatting cells in column up to and including the last one with text entered

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am using Google Sheets and trying to write a custom formatting rule that seems like it should be simple.  I am trying to figure out how to conditionally format all the cells in a column INCLUDING AND ABOVE (but not below) the cell that meets my condition.

I've found a lot of things that will format the entire column, but that's not what I'm looking for.

The image below is a basic example that I manually colored in to do what I want.

It's for my budget spreadsheet, where each row is an entry from a particular date. I have an "Agreement" column that is empty except when I enter the date that I reconciled the budget. I want it to color that cell and all the empty cells above it green, signifying at a glance: "everything up to this point is ok/has been checked over".  Then as time goes by, and I enter another date several rows below, I want it to extend the colored shading up to there.

I've been searching, but it is hard to articulate this; if I say "until this cell" I get results for "shade cell until text is entered"; any mention of "above" and "below" generally relates to the values in the cells; I've found some things about Indirect but just for a single cell above, not for all cells above the current cell.

Wondering if this is even possible...

[Google Sheets example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl0cw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a conditional formatting rule for column A using a Custom Formula you can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(ROW(),"<="&LARGE(ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A100),"TRUE",ROW(A1:A100))),1))
```

The larger the ranges you use, the slower it will be however.

Comment: WHEEEE!  It worked!  Both in my example spreadsheet, and my actual spreadsheet.  I'm trying to make sense of it, and it is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Awesome. It is essentially cycling through each cell in the column, and checking if that row number is <= the last row number with a value in it. Using ISBLANK() checks each cell, and returns an array of TRUE or FALSE values. The IF statement converts any FALSE values (cells that aren't blank) into the ROW number. Using LARGE we can then get the largest row number from that array, which is the last non empty cell.

Comment: Oooh, ok, that's starting to make more sense.  I had looked up all those formulas, but I was having trouble piecing them all together.  The ArrayFormula was the tricky thing, from the docs I wasn't sure what it returned, but from your explanation I see it now!  I would not have guessed that LARGE could compare the row numbers to the string "TRUE".  Thanks!!!